# Docker error !!! bash: docker.exe: command not found

Tags: docker

i installed docker toolbox in window 10 home and now on execute command it show me an error bash:

```
docker.exe: command not found
```

[image]

Comment: try `./docker --version`, does that work?

Comment: Can you restart your system and try again. Hopefully, with restart, it may solve automatically.

Comment: you can migrate to new docker desktop app. It's just a suggestion.
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/docker-toolbox/

Comment: i download this tool box 5 times with latest as well as previous version ,sometime it work fine but it behave like above and it does not show any symbol of docker in bottom tool bar

Answer (score 0):

Found this issue by having a similar error `zsh: command not found: docker.exe`

My issue was an entry in the `~/.zshrc` file that had an alias to docker.exe.
By commenting out the alias and `source ~/.zshrc` the file, docker was able to run.